# How to concatenate multiple valid_referers on NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to figure how to concatenate multiple `valid_referers`

```
location ~* \.(gif|otf|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$ {

    # need help with the line bellow to add multiple domains here
    valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }

}
```

**Will this work?**

```
location ~* \.(gif|otf|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked ~\.notblock-one.com\.notblock-two.com ~\.notblock-three.com\. ~\.notblock-etc.com\.;
    if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }   
}
```